# How do i remove digits from left side of a number in python using only while loops?

Tags: python

How do i remove digits from left side of a number in python using only while loops? For example: if I have number 997, how do i get 97 and later 7. I have tried to remove them but every time I get lost.

Comment: look into the modulo operator `%` that may help

Comment: `I have tried to remove them but every time I get lost.` then show those attempts here. StackOverflow isn't a code writing or tutoring service. You need to put in work in order to get help. This is laid out in the [tour], the [ask] page, this [help/on-topic] topic, and here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6273251

Comment: Show what you've done so far and someone will probably be able to identify where you've gone wrong

Comment: To start from the left, note that `997 // 100 == 9` , and that `divmod(997, 100) == (9, 97)`.

Comment: Can you write code that "removes the digit" once? What happens if you just put that code in the loop? If you can't, what approach did you take to solving the problem? Can you think of a *mathematical* way to get the result, for example using division and remainders? What exactly is the difficulty?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to convert to a string and back like this:

```
def remove_digit(x):
    return int(str(x)[1:])

while x > 10:
    x = remove_digit(x)
    print(x)
```